# OnClick ButterKnife, nothing happens

Tags: java, android, buttonclick, butterknife

I'm trying to use ButterKnife to onClick. I did the code bellow and nothing happens, I've watched tutorials all over the internet, and they do the same thing as I did.

Here is the code

```
@BindView(R.id.startButton) protected ImageButton mStartButton;

@OnClick(R.id.startButton)
public void startTest(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "testing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ButterKnife.bind(MainActivity.this);

}
```

And if I put the method startTest(); inside the OnCreate, the toast is called when the app runs for the first time, what shows that the ButterKnife is working. But I need that to happen only when the button is clicked.

Thanks

Comment: Just as a note, if you are calling `startTest()` in `onCreate`, that does not mean that ButterKnife is working. It just means you are calling the method successfully.

Comment: Just double-checking, could you add `activity_main.xml` to your question as well? Also, if you could try adding `(View view)` as a parameter of your `startTest` method. Shouldn't make any difference, but just want to rule out any ButterKnife oddities. And finally, your app-level `build.gradle`.

Comment: I have these lines in my build.gradle:                                                             compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

Comment: @Felipe See my answer below. I think you're also missing the ButterKnife compiler from your `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned that you have `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'` in your `build.gradle` file. I think you may be missing the corresponding compiler. Add this to your `dependencies` section:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your onCreate method should be public. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

The only two reason i can see are either

1. 'protected' needs to be removed from your ImageView

or

2. 'startButton' is not actually defined in activity_main